# PHP - how to select columns that only have 12 character

Tags: php, sql, database

Example: I want sql to output only rows that have 6 digit of character 'AAAAAA' I don't want rows that have more than that.

Comment: `select * from mytable where len(mycol) = 6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE LENGTH(columnName) = 6" If MySql and
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE LEN(columnName) = 6" If MSSql
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '^[A]{6}$';
```